# Shell Script - Force output to the the command line inside a function

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Im modifying a shell script that is responsible of an installation. The script has several functions, and all the output must be redirected to a log file.
However, in the beginning of every function, I have to print in the terminal something like "Starting function ". What happens is that, when I call a function inside a code block, because I'm redirecting the output of that code block to a log file, everything is redirected, even the first information that I want to show in the terminal.

**Example of a function:**

```
function_xpto() {
        echo -n "starting function ...."

        if  (   {
                    command1 && command2 && ... && commandN;
                } >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
            );
        then
            echo "SUCCESS"
        else
            echo "FAILED"
            exit 1
        fi;
}
```

**Example of a call to the function:**

```
        echo -n "running script"

        if  (   {
                    command1 && function_xpto;
                } >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
            );
        then
            echo "SUCCESS"
        else
            echo "FAILED"
            exit 1
        fi;
```

When I call the function inside the code block, everything (and I understand why) is redirected.

So, I want a way to force a command (eg: echo) to be sent to the terminal, or at least, to don't be sent to the log file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/tty` is the controlling terminal for a process, if it has one.

```
function_xpto() {
        echo -n "starting function ...." > /dev/tty

        if  (   {
                    command1 && command2 && ... && commandN;
                } >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
            );
        then
            echo "SUCCESS"
        else
            echo "FAILED"
            exit 1
        fi;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. One question, it forces to send to the terminal? Or send it to the terminal and to the log file?

Comment: Just the terminal. If you want to send the same output to two different files, you need to use `tee`: `echo -n "Starting function ... " | tee -a /dev/tty` sends the output of `echo` both to `/dev/tty` and standard output (whatever that may be). `tee` writes its standard input to standard output (just like `cat`), but also to any files whose names are passed as arguments. The `-a` option ensures that any named files are appended to, not overwritten. With `/dev/tty`, `-a` is probably unnecessary, since you can't truncate that particular device.

Comment: Thank you. I just start learning shell script two days ago, so almost everything is new to me. Thanks

Comment: @chepner `sudo rm -f /dev/tty ; ./script.sh` Your solution _might_ work in some cases, but does not guarantee that the output is written to the terminal.

Comment: Your scenario is a lot less likely than mine. Willful subversion of the file system is quite a bigger problem than ordinary program execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo -n "running script" > /proc/$PPID/fd/1
```

Example for @chepner:

```
$ cat subshell.sh
#!/bin/bash
write () { echo noppid
echo echowithppid > /proc/$PPID/fd/1
}
write >/dev/null 2>&1
$ ./subshell.sh
echowithppid
$
```

Comment: `fd/1` is standard output, which may or may not be the terminal.

Comment: ^^ Try `bash -c './subshell.sh; true' >/dev/null`

Comment: Thanks. It works too. but, as I asked the user above, it forces to send to the terminal? Or send it to the terminal and to the log file (if it is the case)?

Comment: @IporSircer: `bash -c ':; bash subshell.sh' > /dev/null`. (The no-op command `:` ensures that `bash -c` doesn't optimize away the process used to run `subshell.sh`. Your solution *might* work in some cases, but does not *guarantee* that the output is written to the terminal.